# Show that a subsequence of a Markov chain is itself a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

"Let $X = (X_{n})_{n \geq 0}$ be a Markov chain and and let $(n_r)_{r \geq 0}$ be an unbounded increasing sequence of positive integers. Show that $Y_r = X_{n_r}$ defines a (possibly inhomogeneous) Markov chain."

I tried using the usual Markov condition and filling in the gaps by inserting the missing $X_i$ and summing, but I'm not quite sure what it is I even have to sum over.

Comment: Seems like you should only have to go back to $X_{n_{r-1}}$, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I was hoping someone could show me what I'm supposed to express the Markov condition as.

Comment: I simply meant that $P(X_{n_r} \mid X_{n_r-1}, X_{n_r-2}, \ldots) = P(X_{n_r} \mid X_{n_r-1}, X_{n_r-2} \ldots, X_{n_{r-1}+1}, X_{n_{r-1}})$; i.e., you can truncate the full history at $X_{n_{r-1}}$.

Comment: I see. How did you arrive at that though? And how would I use it to solve the problem?

Comment: Roughly speaking, whatever dependency $X_{n_{r-1}+1}$ has on its history can be summed up by $X_{n_{r-1}} \equiv Y_{r-1}$. Can you use that as a base case in an induction that goes forward to $X_{n_r} \equiv Y_r$?